# Bitmaps not displaying in pebble aplite

Tags: bitmap, pebble-sdk

So, I'm having problems displaying bitmaps, in aplite, not basalt. Yes, I know it's something to do with the amount of memory, but when I look at heap_bytes_free, and take memory fragmentation into account, I still don't see what the problem is.

Below, I show some code and some debug output from the logs, and it seems in the second case, there is an inordinate amount of memory being grabbed to display my bitmap.

I'm displaying two bitmaps, of similar sizes. The first, compassWindow.png, only uses 3K in aplite and 6k in basalt. The second, decimalBackground.png uses 22k in basalt (yes 22,560 bytes!) and fails to be created in aplite.

When running in aplite, I get no error message. The bitmap just fails to display. So what's happening?

Here's the logs from the same code being run on the two platforms pebble original (aplite), and pebble Time (basalt)

SDK 4.0.1 Ubuntu VirtualBox under Windoows 10. App 3.8.1-942-b60f188, Watch v3.8.2 (OG and Time)
Here's the code. I have put an APP_LOG before and after the gbitmap_create_with_resource command.
a) the compass bitmap

```
    bitmap_layer =  bitmap_layer_create(GRect(0, 0, 144,168));
APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "COMPASS  Free: %d ", heap_bytes_free());
    gBitMap = gbitmap_create_with_resource(RESOURCE_ID_COMPASS);
APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "COMPASS %d Free: %d ", (int) gBitMap, heap_bytes_free());
    bitmap_layer_set_bitmap    (bitmap_layer, gBitMap );
```

b) the decimalBackground bitmap

```
     bitmap_layer =  bitmap_layer_create(GRect(0, 0, 144,300));
APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "decimalBackground Free: %d ",  heap_bytes_free());
    gBitMap = gbitmap_create_with_resource(RESOURCE_ID_DECIMALBACKGROUND);
APP_LOG(APP_LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG, "decimalBackground %d Free: %d ", (int) gBitMap, heap_bytes_free());
    bitmap_layer_set_bitmap    (bitmap_layer, gBitMap);
```

Here are the resource definitions in appinfo.json. You'll notice I'm using the new unified "bitmap" type.

```
    "media": [
{
        "type": "bitmap",
        "name": "COMPASS",
        "file": "images/compassWindow.png"
      },

{
        "type": "bitmap",
        "name": "DECIMALBACKGROUND",
        "file": "images/decimalBackground.png"
      },
```

Here's the output:
1. basalt:

```
[10:54:44] wind_dir.c:101> COMPASS  Free: 45928 
[10:54:44] wind_dir.c:103> COMPASS 537019168 Free: 39664 
[10:54:44] msg_handler.c:46> current window: startWind
13 seconds later
[10:54:57] javascript> raceQs V0.81:294 Current Window: performance
[10:54:57] position.c:171> decimalBackground Free: 46132 
[10:54:57] position.c:173> decimalBackground 537019212 Free: 23572
```

Note: at 10:54:44, the bytes free go from 45928 to 39644 - a difference of 6264

At 10:54:57, they go from 46132 to 23572 - a difference of 22,560.
2. aplite:

```
[10:47:13] wind_dir.c:101> COMPASS  Free: 4856 
[10:47:14] wind_dir.c:103> COMPASS 536994972 Free: 1776 

[10:47:20] position.c:171> decimalBackground Free: 5060 
[10:47:20] position.c:173> decimalBackground 0 Free: 5060
```

At 10:47:14 the bytes free go from 4865 to 1776 - difference of 3080.
At 10:47:20 the  bytes_free don't change because the gbitmap_create_with_resource(RESOURCE_ID_DECIMALBACKGROUND);fails.
And here are the images., file sizes :

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 alan alan 2772 Oct 14 11:55 compassWindow.png
```

[image: CompassWindow.png]

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 alan alan 1637 Jan 18 16:02 decimalBackground.png
```

[image: decimalBackground.png]

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that you are trying to set an image that is too big in that bitmap layer. I had a similar problem with aplite for a big horizontal image. I noticed that if the bitmap_layer is bigger than the screen it doesn't appear. I think it can be a bit bigger but definetely not double height or something like that.

What I did was chopping my image in 2 and changing one for the other when needed.